# Passing the paths of nuget installed assemblies to mono runtime

Tags: c#, mono, nuget

I have Visual Studio project that I am trying to get running with Mono.

I could install all dependencies using

```
mono nuget.exe install
```

and compile my application using

```
mcs -r:RestSharp.105.2.3/lib/net46/RestSharp.dll \
        -r:JWT.1.3.4/lib/3.5/JWT.dll  \
        -r:jose-jwt.2.2.0/lib/net461/jose-jwt.dll \
        -r:Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll \
        Program.cs
```

Now I am trying to run the application using

```
mono Program.exe

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

So how do you pass the path to the assemblies to the Mono runtime similar to the compiler?

I tried to set $MONO_PATH but this is not working and not recommended for Production.

The overall question how the mcs compiler and the mono runtime could get the information directly from the installed packages (using nuget.exe).

Comment: You are not using a "Visual Studio project" at all but the compiler directly, as that would use Copy Local to address the issue. Why? You are asking something obviously you know the answer, right?

Comment: The question is pretty clear, isn't it? As said: the project is a project created under Visual Studio...it's a single file mini project...I want to get it compiled and runnable a Linux box without Visual Studio.

Comment: On Mono you should use xbuild or MSBuild to compile .csproj project files. Don't attempt to compile directly using C# compiler, which is clearly a tougher way.